# Improving performance of raycaster application

Tags: c++, performance, sdl, raycasting

[Bitbucket link to repo](https://bitbucket.org/daniel_kashtan/raycaster/src/1f26fab702403f1bb04e303d4d5a7b7d52b6bc43/RayCaster1.cpp#lines-15)

[Tutorial I have been following](https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html)

I decided to make a raycaster app and try to understand how it really works. So far so good, I have it up and running. If you download the source and execute make, it should pop out a test.exe. I am developing on Ubunutu using Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. I have made changes to the tutorial and I have tried to code it from scratch while following the tutorial's algorithm. Performance is okay, but at 900x900 on my laptop, the frame-rate is about 40fps, which seems low. I cannot figure out where the bottlenecks are at this point. I'd expect to be clearing 100fps easily.

RayCaster1.cpp

```
#include "include/SDLWrapper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 900

#define mapWidth 24
#define mapHeight 24

//export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0
//run vcxsrv in windows "XLaunch"
//make sure to check access control checkbox and uncheck the opengl option
//./test.exe

int worldMap[mapWidth][mapHeight]=
{
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,0,0,0,5,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};

uint32_t* rasterPixels = new uint32_t[WINDOW_WIDTH*WINDOW_WIDTH]; 
double posX = 22, posY = 12;  //x and y start position
double dirX = -1, dirY = 0; //initial direction vector
double planeX = 0, planeY = 0.66; //the 2d raycaster version of camera plane

double moveSpeed; //the constant value is in squares/second
double rotSpeed; //the constant value is in radians/second

uint32_t red = 16711680;
uint32_t dark_red = 8388608;
uint32_t green = 65280;
uint32_t dark_green = 32768;
uint32_t blue = 255;
uint32_t dark_blue = 128;
uint32_t white = 16777215;
uint32_t gray = 8421504;
uint32_t yellow = 16776960;
uint32_t dark_yellow = 8421376;

void initRasterPixels(){
    //Fill the raster with pixel information
    for(int i = 0; i < WINDOW_WIDTH; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < WINDOW_WIDTH; j++){
          rasterPixels[i+(WINDOW_WIDTH*j)] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void addVerticalLineOfPixels(int row, uint32_t* rasterPixels, uint32_t color, int start, int end) {
    for(int i = 0; i < WINDOW_WIDTH; i++) {
        if(i >= start && i <= end) {
            rasterPixels[(i*WINDOW_WIDTH)+row] = color;
        } else {
             rasterPixels[(i*WINDOW_WIDTH)+row] = 0;
        }
    }
}

uint32_t* generateRaster(KeyboardState keyboardState, double frameTime){

    if (keyboardState.keyUp)
    {
      if(worldMap[int(posX + dirX * moveSpeed)][int(posY)] == false) posX += dirX * moveSpeed;
      if(worldMap[int(posX)][int(posY + dirY * moveSpeed)] == false) posY += dirY * moveSpeed;
    }
    //move backwards if no wall behind you
    if (keyboardState.keyDown)
    {
      if(worldMap[int(posX - dirX * moveSpeed)][int(posY)] == false) posX -= dirX * moveSpeed;
      if(worldMap[int(posX)][int(posY - dirY * moveSpeed)] == false) posY -= dirY * moveSpeed;
    }
    //rotate to the right
    if (keyboardState.keyRight)
    {
      //both camera direction and camera plane must be rotated
      double oldDirX = dirX;
      dirX = dirX * cos(-rotSpeed) - dirY * sin(-rotSpeed);
      dirY = oldDirX * sin(-rotSpeed) + dirY * cos(-rotSpeed);
      double oldPlaneX = planeX;
      planeX = planeX * cos(-rotSpeed) - planeY * sin(-rotSpeed);
      planeY = oldPlaneX * sin(-rotSpeed) + planeY * cos(-rotSpeed);
    }
    //rotate to the left
    if (keyboardState.keyLeft)
    {
      //both camera direction and camera plane must be rotated
      double oldDirX = dirX;
      dirX = dirX * cos(rotSpeed) - dirY * sin(rotSpeed);
      dirY = oldDirX * sin(rotSpeed) + dirY * cos(rotSpeed);
      double oldPlaneX = planeX;
      planeX = planeX * cos(rotSpeed) - planeY * sin(rotSpeed);
      planeY = oldPlaneX * sin(rotSpeed) + planeY * cos(rotSpeed);
    }

    //main for loop for calculating wall heights
    for(int x = 0; x < WINDOW_WIDTH; x++) {
        //calculate ray position and direction
        double cameraX = 2 * x / double(WINDOW_WIDTH) - 1; //x-coordinate in camera space, normalized, -1 is left, 1 is right, 0 is center
        double rayDirX = dirX + planeX * cameraX;
        double rayDirY = dirY + planeY * cameraX;

        //which box of the map we are in
        int mapX = int(posX);
        int mapY = int(posY);

        //length of ray from current position to next x or y-side
        double sideDistX;
        double sideDistY;

        //length of ray from one x or y-side to next x or y-side
        double deltaDistX = abs(1 / rayDirX);
        double deltaDistY = abs(1 / rayDirY);
        double perpWallDist;

        //what direction to step in x or y-direction (either +1 or -1)
        int stepX;
        int stepY;

        int hit = 0;
        int side; //0 is x-side hit, 1 is y-side hit

        //calculate step and initial sideDist
        if (rayDirX < 0)
        {
            stepX = -1;
            sideDistX = (posX - mapX) * deltaDistX;
        }
        else
        {
            stepX = 1;
            sideDistX = (mapX + 1.0 - posX) * deltaDistX;
        }
        if (rayDirY < 0)
        {
            stepY = -1;
            sideDistY = (posY - mapY) * deltaDistY;
        }
        else
        {
            stepY = 1;
            sideDistY = (mapY + 1.0 - posY) * deltaDistY;
        }

    //perform DDA
      while (hit == 0)
      {
        //jump to next map square, OR in x-direction, OR in y-direction
        if (sideDistX < sideDistY)
        {
          sideDistX += deltaDistX;
          mapX += stepX;
          side = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          sideDistY += deltaDistY;
          mapY += stepY;
          side = 1;
        }
        //Check if ray has hit a wall
        if (worldMap[mapX][mapY] > 0) hit = 1;
      }

      //Calculate distance projected on camera direction (Euclidean distance will give fisheye effect!)
      if (side == 0) perpWallDist = (mapX - posX + (1 - stepX) / 2) / rayDirX;
      else           perpWallDist = (mapY - posY + (1 - stepY) / 2) / rayDirY; 

      //Calculate height of line to draw on screen
      int lineHeight = (int)(WINDOW_WIDTH / perpWallDist);

      //calculate lowest and highest pixel to fill in current stripe
      int drawStart = -lineHeight / 2 + WINDOW_WIDTH / 2;
      if(drawStart < 0)drawStart = 0;
      int drawEnd = lineHeight / 2 + WINDOW_WIDTH / 2;
      if(drawEnd >= WINDOW_WIDTH)drawEnd = WINDOW_WIDTH - 1;

      //choose wall color
      uint32_t color;
      //give x and y sides different brightness
      if (side == 1) {
        switch(worldMap[mapX][mapY])
        {
          case 1:  color = dark_red;  break; //red
          case 2:  color = dark_green;  break; //green
          case 3:  color = dark_blue;   break; //blue
          case 4:  color = gray;  break; //white
          default: color = dark_yellow; break; //yellow
        }
      } else {
        switch(worldMap[mapX][mapY])
        {  
          case 1:  color = red;  break; //red
          case 2:  color = green;  break; //green
          case 3:  color = blue;   break; //blue
          case 4:  color = white;  break; //white
          default: color = yellow; break; //yellow
        }
      }

      //draw the pixels of the stripe as a vertical line
      uint32_t column[WINDOW_WIDTH];
      addVerticalLineOfPixels(x, rasterPixels, color, drawStart, drawEnd);
    }

    //speed modifiers
    moveSpeed = frameTime * 5.0;
    rotSpeed = frameTime * 3.0;

  return rasterPixels;
}

//Need a separate method here to handle input. The SDLWrapper will send inkeys and keypressed to be operated on here
//and have access to all the file scope vars like pos, wroldmap, dir, plane

int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    SDLWrapper sdlWrapper;

    initRasterPixels();
    sdlWrapper.setupSDLRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, generateRaster);
};
```

SDLWrapper.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "include/SDLWrapper.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define TICK_INTERVAL 4

static Uint32 next_time;

double currTime = 0; //time of current frame
double oldTime = 0; //time of previous frame

double frameTime; //frameTime is the time this frame has taken, in seconds

TTF_Font* sans_font;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//KEYBOARD FUNCTIONS////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

bool SDLWrapper::keyDown(int key) //this checks if the key is held down, returns true all the time until the key is up
{
  return (inkeys[key] != 0);
}

bool SDLWrapper::keyPressed(int key) //this checks if the key is *just* pressed, returns true only once until the key is up again
{
  if(keypressed.find(key) == keypressed.end()) keypressed[key] = false;
  if(inkeys[key])
  {
    if(keypressed[key] == false)
    {
      keypressed[key] = true;
      return true;
    }
  }
  else keypressed[key] = false;

  return false;
}

///// End of KEYBOARD FUNCTIONS ////

int SDLWrapper::setupSDLRenderer(int WINDOW_WIDTH, uint32_t* (*generateRaster)(KeyboardState, double)){
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Window *window;
    bool run = true;
    KeyboardState keyboardState;
    uint32_t color = 0;

    printf("setupSDLRenderer start");

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("test", 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_WIDTH, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    // https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157604/how-to-get-access-to-framebuffer-as-a-uint32-t-in-sdl2
    SDL_Texture* framebuffer = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_WIDTH);
    uint32_t* pixels = new uint32_t[WINDOW_WIDTH*WINDOW_WIDTH];  

    if(TTF_Init()==-1) {
        printf("TTF_Init: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
        exit(2);
    }
    sans_font = TTF_OpenFont("font/Sans.ttf", 12); //this opens a font style and sets a size
    if(!sans_font) {
        printf("TTF_OpenFont: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
    }

    SDL_Rect message_rect; //create a rect
    message_rect.x = 0;  //controls the rect's x coordinate 
    message_rect.y = 0; // controls the rect's y coordinte
    message_rect.w = 20; // controls the width of the rect
    message_rect.h = 20; // controls the height of the rect
    SDL_Texture* message;

    next_time = SDL_GetTicks() + TICK_INTERVAL;
    while (run) {
        //Start of future render function
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        rasterPixels = (*generateRaster)(keyboardState, frameTime);

        SDL_UpdateTexture(framebuffer , NULL, rasterPixels, WINDOW_WIDTH * sizeof (uint32_t));
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, framebuffer , NULL, NULL);
        // printf("time_left: %d", time_left());
        SDL_Delay(time_left()); //remove this to allow for more than 60 iterations a second
        next_time = SDL_GetTicks() + TICK_INTERVAL;

        //timing for input and FPS counter
        oldTime = currTime;
        currTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        frameTime = (currTime - oldTime) * 0.001; //frameTime is the time this frame has taken, in seconds
        SDL_Color White = {255, 255, 255};  // this is the color in rgb format, maxing out all would give you the color white, and it will be your text's color
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << (int)(1.0 / frameTime);
        const char* str = ss.str().c_str();
        SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(sans_font, str, White); // as TTF_RenderText_Solid could only be used on SDL_Surface then you have to create the surface first
        message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage); //now you can convert it into a texture

        //Now since it's a texture, you have to put RenderCopy in your game loop area, the area where the whole code executes
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, message, NULL, &message_rect); //you put the renderer's name first, the Message, the crop size(you can ignore this if you don't want to dabble with cropping), and the rect which is the size and coordinate of your texture

        //Don't forget too free your surface and texture
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            keyboardState.reset();

            //Start of handleInput function
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                run = false;
            }
            inkeys = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
            if (keyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_UP) || keyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_W)) {
                keyboardState.keyUp = true;
            } else if (keyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN) || keyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_S)) {
                keyboardState.keyDown = true;
            } else if (keyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT) || keyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_A)) {
                keyboardState.keyLeft = true;
            } else if (keyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT) || keyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_D)) {
                keyboardState.keyRight = true;
            }
            //End of handleInput function
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

uint32_t SDLWrapper::peek(int x, int y, int WINDOW_WIDTH){
    return rasterPixels[x+(WINDOW_WIDTH*y)];
}

int SDLWrapper::time_left(void)
{
    Uint32 now;

    now = SDL_GetTicks();

    //rendered too slow, don't wait
    if(next_time < now) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        // rendered too fast, wait until the next tick amount
        return next_time - now;
    }
}

void KeyboardState::reset(){
      keyUp = false;
      keyDown = false;
      keyLeft = false;
      keyRight = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest figuring out how to use a cpu profiler for your particular platform (Visual Studio has a nice one, but there are simpler ones like "Very Sleepy" to give a quick overview).

These will sample your code as it runs (make sure you run an optimized build, not a debug build), and provide detailed feedback as to which line of code takes up the most time.

---

I put together a quick test project with your code, and ran it under Very Sleepy, which provides output like the following:

```
Name                    Exclusive   Inclusive   %Exclusive  %Inclusive  Module  Source File                                                             Source Line Address

generateRaster          13.94s      13.94s      77.24%      77.24%      App     D:\Projects\SDLProject\Code\App\main.cpp                                332         0x7ff6550b14ea
memcpy                  0.98s       0.98s       5.43%       5.43%       App     d:\A01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\crt\vcruntime\src\string\amd64\memcpy.asm  436         0x7ff65516f120
[00007FF934D6EFD0]      0.01s       0.01s       0.04%       0.04%       App                                                                             0           0x7ff934d6efd0
D3D_UpdateTextureRep    0.01s       0.99s       0.04%       5.50%       App     D:\Projects\SDLProject\Code\SDL\src\render\direct3d\SDL_render_d3d.c    760         0x7ff6550c7b6c
```

So a quick glance shows that more than 75% of the time spent running the program was in the `generateRaster` function.

It also gives a line by line overview of where the time is spent. (Some lines don't really show up due to optimizations).

[image: profiler hot lines]

We can see that `addVerticalLineOfPixels()` is the culprit.

```
void addVerticalLineOfPixels(int row, uint32_t* rasterPixels, uint32_t color, int start, int end) {
    for(int i = 0; i < WINDOW_WIDTH; i++) {
        if(i >= start && i <= end) {
            rasterPixels[(i*WINDOW_WIDTH)+row] = color;
        } else {
             rasterPixels[(i*WINDOW_WIDTH)+row] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't very surprising, since the function effectively touches every single pixel on our screen texture.

We might try to reduce the number of pixels we have to touch by clearing the texture some other way (e.g. blitting to it on the GPU instead). This means we'd only have to manually set the pixels between `start` and `end` to `color`.

However, even if we did that, there's another problem which is described at the very bottom of the linked tutorial:

> Raycasting works with vertical stripes, but the screen buffer in
> memory is laid out with horizontal scanlines. So drawing vertical
> stripes is bad for memory locality for caching (it is in fact a worst
> case scenario), and the loss of good caching may hurt the speed more
> than some of the 3D computations on modern machines. It may be
> possible to program this with better caching behavior (e.g. processing
> multiple stripes at once, using a cache-oblivious transpose algorithm,
> or having a 90 degree rotated raycaster), but for simplicity the rest
> of this tutorial ignores this caching issue.

In other words, using `rasterPixels[(i*WINDOW_WIDTH)+row] = ...` skips across a large amount of memory, and only sets a single pixel in every `WINDOW_WIDTH`. We repeat this skipping for every column in the texture.

Instead, we would like to do `rasterPixels[row * WINDOW_WIDTH + i] = ...`, so we set every pixel in a contiguous block.

It's actually a simple change:

```
void addVerticalLineOfPixels(int row, uint32_t* rP, uint32_t color, int start, int end) {
    std::fill_n(rP + (row * WINDOW_WIDTH), start, 0);
    std::fill_n(rP + (row * WINDOW_WIDTH) + start, (end - start), color);
    std::fill_n(rP + (row * WINDOW_WIDTH) + end, (WINDOW_WIDTH - end), 0);
}
```

(We use `std::fill_n` for neatness and performance - we're effectively doing 3 loops over the index ranges `[0, start)`, `[start, end)` and `[end, WINDOW_WIDTH)` ).

Then we can replace the texture blitting function `SDL_RenderCopy` with `SDL_RenderCopyEx`, which lets us rotate the texture while blitting:

```
SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, framebuffer, NULL, NULL, -90.0, NULL, SDL_RendererFlip::SDL_FLIP_NONE);
```

Measuring these changes with the profiler shows that `generateRaster` now takes up <2.5% of the program run time.

`:)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to cross-compile to windows using mingw compiler. When I run this app in Windows natively, it runs much faster, well over 200fps on my laptop at 900x900 instead of 40-60fps. I believe if I was running this natively on linux and not with wsl2 I would have never had performance concerns.